# Check user is within geofencing (Location boundaries) or not

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, codeigniter-3, geofencing

One of my applications is already developed, I want to add a new feature in it to add geofencing on MAP.

While user is book a bike from A location , After some time user end his/her ride at location B, At that time I have to check user is park bike within geofencing or not.

Can you please suggest me how to create geofencing over map and how to check user is within geofencing or not.

Can you please give me any idea how to develop this feature ?

Comment: is it a circular fence where you know where the center is?  If it is you can just use the Haversine formular to calculate the distance by a lat & long from the center of the fence to where the user parked the bike.

Comment: Perfectly valid comment above. If your boundaries is a Polygon instead of a circle, there is a documented method to check whether a point falls within a Polygon in the Geometry library: [containsLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?#containsLocation).

Comment: give us a bit of your code so then will be easier to help you